# Is it possible to force hardware acceleration on a CSS width transition

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have noticed jerky laggy performance when I change an elements width or margin with CSS transitions.

Is there anyway to force hardware acceleration? Is there any way to use transform properties to achieve a seamingly similar result?

Comment: could you fiddle an example? Id like to see what you mean.

Comment: On phone. Will do later. Thanks

Comment: You could always `scaleX(2.0)` on your desired element and `scaleX(0.5)` on its children.  It's a pretty crappy solution though as the content won't reflow to the new size.

Comment: @josh. Could work though with overflow hidden.

Comment: I don't see how `overflow: hidden` would help that, as the content is just going to be its original size in a container that's twice as wide.  Really, you'd need to add content dynamically after the resize.  There's not a way I intuitively know to do this without incorporating some kind of JavaScript.  It's probably not a lot of JavaScript, but there would need to be a combination of JavaScript and probably layering of sibling divs, which is messy to say the least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really.  Hardware acceleration depends on a lot of factors, none of them under javascript control.

Which leaves us the question of how to improve CSS width/margin transition performance, and the answer is usually "replace it with scale", because it can be done cheaply on GPU and because it doesn't trigger reflow.

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/
- http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/
- [Improving CSS3 transition performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643240/improving-css3-transition-performance)
- [Jerky CSS transform transition in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605731/jerky-css-transform-transition-in-chrome)

It is also known that Chrome does not do as well a job accelerating CSS transitions as Firefox and IE.

- [Why transitions for some CSS properties are slow and none fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347701/why-transitions-for-some-css-properties-are-slow-and-none-fluent)
- [CSS3 transform difference in Firefox and Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179758/css3-transform-difference-in-firefox-and-chrome-and-ie)
- http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2014/02/fixing-css-transitions-in-google-chrome/

In fact, given that Google rejected Pointer Event [on the ground of speed](http://microsoft-news.com/google-drops-support-for-microsofts-pointer-events-standard-in-chrome-browsers-citing-lame-reasons/), which IE [solved by GPU acceleration](http://www.citeworld.com/article/2466844/development/google-pointer-events-retreat.html), it can be said that Chrome (and Webkit in general - Safari is even slower) is lagging behind on this front, and the only way to help is [contributing code to Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/developers/contributing-code) / [Webkit](http://www.webkit.org/).

I'd rather switch to a quicker transition.